# why node-sp-auth on demand doesn't show browser window?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, electron

I'm trying to setup a brand new angular 9 application local development environment for a SPA SharePoint Online application.

As part of the process I need to setup the local proxy server [sp-rest-proxy](https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-rest-proxy). I configured it to use on demand credentials. This is the `config/private.json` content:

```
{
  "siteUrl": "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite",
  "strategy": "OnDemandCredentials",
  "ondemand": true
}
```

My `package.json` file includes:

```
{
   "scripts": {
       "serve": "node src/server.js"
    }
}
```

`server.js` content is:

```
const RestProxy = require('sp-rest-proxy');

const settings = {
  configPath: './config/private.json', // Location for SharePoint instance mapping and credentials
  port: 8080, // Local server port
  staticRoot: './node_modules/sp-rest-proxy/static' // Root folder for static content
};

const restProxy = new RestProxy(settings);
restProxy.serve();
```

I run:

```
npm run serve
```

Open browser and point it to `http://localhost:8080` when I try to execute a simple request like `/_api/web?$select=Title` I get the following error:

```
{
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseText": "Command failed: C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /d /s /c \"electron C:\\projects\\MyProject\\node_modules\\node-sp-auth\\lib\\src\\auth\\resolvers\\ondemand\\electron\\main.js https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/diner false\"",
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

No browser window is shown.

I have electron installed globally.

When I execute the following on the command line:

```
electron C:\projects\MyProject\node_modules\node-sp-auth\lib\src\auth\resolvers\ondemand\electron\main.js https://tenant.sharepoint.com false
```

Nothing happens, the process ends with no messages, no browser window is opened.

What can I do to find and fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved after upgrading sp-rest-proxy to version 2.11.1.

See [this issue](https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-rest-proxy/issues/104#issuecomment-627922539) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

On-Demand auth requires Electron being installed `npm i -g electron@6`.

Electron is optional in node-sp-auth, as it's huge it was an architectural decision making it optional and for manual install only for that rare cases when On-Demand is needed.